# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated when load function is called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have two pages login page and forgot password page I want to hide form on login page and load there forgot page content on hyperlink click. But when I click hyperlink login page loads it self into div which is specified for forgot page and console throws this warning.

`Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Im using jquery load function for this

Heres js:

```
$(function() {
    $(".forgotPassword").click(function() {
        $(".login-block").hide();
        $(".frame-container").load("forgotPassword.jsp");
        return false;
    });

    $('input[name="send"]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var params = "email=" + $(".email").val(); 

        $.ajax({
            url:$(".forgot-block").attr("action"),
            type: 'get',
            data: params,
            sucess: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Heres loginpage.jsp:

```
<body>
    <center>
        <div class="center-container">
            <div id="header">
                <div class="login-header">KOŠICE <span>DEVICES</span></div>
                <div id="nav" class="login-nav" ></div>
            </div>
            <div id="login-error">${error}</div>
            <form action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"></c:url>" method="post" role="form" class="login-block">
                <p>WELCOME, PLEASE LOG IN!</p>
                <p >
                    <!-- <label for="j_username">Email</label> -->
                    <input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <!-- <label for="j_password">Password</label> --> 
                    <input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" name="login" id="j_login" value="Log In" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="#" class="forgotPassword">FORGOT PASSWORD ?</a>
                </p>
            </form>
            <div class="frame-container"></div>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

Heres forgotpassword.jsp:

```
<form action="/forgotPassword" method="post" role="form" class="forgot-block">
    <p>ENTER YOUR EMAIL</p>
    <p><input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="email"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="send" id="j_login" value="Send" /></p>
</form>
```

js script is loaded in head of loginpage as external script.

Comment: Your ajax call isnt doing a synchronous request, unless you have `$.ajaxSetup({async:false});` somewhere. [.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) defaults to asynchronous calls unless the `async` option is set to false. Are you doing some other ajax calls somewhere? Also your success callback property is misspelled: `sucess: function(data)`

Comment: this is the only ajax call which is called  $('input[name="send"]').click(function(e) is for forgot password page

Comment: on .forgot-password click load function should load the forgot password page